# clojure - list all permutations of a list

Tags: clojure

Say I have a set like this:

```
#{"word1" "word2" "word3"}
```

How could I list all ways that these words might be ordered, i.e.

```
word1 word2 word3
word2 word3 word1
word3 word2 word1
```

etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way is using [math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/):

```
user> (require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as combo])
nil
user> (combo/permutations #{"word1" "word2" "word3"})
(("word1" "word2" "word3") ("word1" "word3" "word2") ("word2" "word1" "word3") ("word2" "word3"    "word1") ("word3" "word1" "word2") ("word3" "word2" "word1"))
```

Edit: I haven't looked at the math.combinatorics implementation, but here's a lazy version because OP asked for some code to follow.

```
(defn permutations [s]
  (lazy-seq
   (if (seq (rest s))
     (apply concat (for [x s]
                     (map #(cons x %) (permutations (remove #{x} s)))))
     [s])))
```

Comment: I am getting "ISeq from: experiment.core$eval261$fn__262" when trying your implementation of permutation. Calling it as (println (permutations #("w" "d" "m"))). Is it because I can't print a lazy-sequence?

Comment: `#("w" "d" "m")` is the syntax for an anonymous function. You want `#{"w" "d" "m"}` @stevemacn

Comment: Is there any reason why `(remove #{x} s)` would be preferred over `(disj s x)`?

Answer (score 12):

Although math.combinatorics is probably the right answer, I was looking for something simpler to follow.  Below is a non-lazy implementation that I can follow:

```
(defn permutations [colls]
  (if (= 1 (count colls))
    (list colls)
    (for [head colls
          tail (permutations (disj (set colls) head))]
      (cons head tail))))
```